# SPUtility.SendEmail() with attachment (.ics files)

Tags: 2010, email, sputility

We send the email from SharePoint by using SPUtility.SendEmail() method. But, now I need to attach multiple .ics file (Outlook meeting requests) with this email.

I have only one option, I have to use the SPUtility method only. How can we acheive this goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no possibility to send Attachments using this method. But you can use of SPAdministrationWebApplication to get the SMTP server details.

Here is the sample code:

```
//Get the Sharepoint SMTP information from the SPAdministrationWebApplication
string smtpServer = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.OutboundMailServiceInstance
.Server.Address;
string smtpFrom = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.OutboundMailSenderAddress;

//Create the mail message and supply it with from and to info

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(smtpFrom, insert_receiver);

//Set the subject and body of the message
mailMessage.Subject = insert_subject;
mailMessage.Body = insert_body;

//Download the content of the file with a WebClient
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

//Supply the WebClient with the network credentials of our user
webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

//Download the byte array of the file
byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(insert_ attachment_url);

//Dump the byte array in a memory stream because
//we can write it to our attachment
MemoryStream memoryStreamOfFile = new MemoryStream(data);

//Add the attachment
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStreamOfFile, insert_filename_attachment, insert_content_type));

//Create the SMTP client object and send the message
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

[Link to source](http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2007/10/02/how-to-send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-from-sharepoint/)

Comment: what should I put instead of **insert_ attachment_url** ?